# Simulate text typing from clipboard

Tags: virtual-keyboard

I am wondering If there any good program, which can simulate text typing from clipboard, especially for Visual Studio?

I have tried AutoHotKey, but it works awfully with line endings, tabs and curly braces. It produces a mess, instead of beautiful code from clipboard.

Comment: You may benefit from taking a look at CopyQ (https://github.com/hluk/CopyQ) and NirCmd (https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/nircmd.html).  I have used both of these tools at one time or another to enter clipboard text into another application.  I have never tried this with Visual Studio.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[ArsClip](http://www.joejoesoft.com/vcms/97/) is a Clipboard Manager that can mimic typing instead of traditional paste.

Windows only.

Answer (score 1):

It might be a bit of a silly suggestion, but since you've mentioned Visual Studio I assume you are capable of at least some basic programming. What you can do is create a WinForms application which listens for a specific key/key combo (you might want WinAPI hooking specifically for that, there are guides online for this, IIRC you need to import like 2 functions from `User32.dll` and pass along the keycodes to listen for), and once your triggers are met, get text from the clipboard (using the `Clipboard` class in `System.Windows.Forms`) and pass it to the `SendKeys` class (also from the `Forms` namespace). You will need to do some string replacements for it to work with newlines and tabs as these are encoded with a specific format in `SendKeys` (think codes like "{Tab}").

Comment: Yep, you're totally right, I'm capable of programming at C# language. However, I thought that for such simple task, a simple relevant solution must be exists. It's really hard to trust that this is only my idea to simulate text typing from clipboard. That's why I prefer to find existing solution, at least before trying to do it myself.